# Dynamic PySimpleGUI Button (Python)

Tags: python, image, button, text, pysimplegui

So let's say I have a button that displays a word, and when I click it, I want it to show an image, which I do like this:

```
x,y=event
window_play.FindElement(event).Update(image_filename=(imgs_path + os.sep + "Back.png"))
```

It works as expected. But what I'm struggling with is getting back to the original view after a second click. I've thought about making a copy of this button (it's actually a matrix of buttons (that's why X and Y, but let's focus on one)) and keeping the status in a boolean (matrix of booleans), which may or may not work, but that's not the bug itself. The thing is, I'm not sure how to do it, wether update the whole button, or just the text, or.. what (when true/false).
I've thought about playing with elements visibility, but not entirely sure how.

Thanks in advance for any tip.

Answer (score 1):

Better to create a blank image used for button if without image.

Demo code for you, no image file here, so use internal base64 encode image from PySimpleGUI and create one same size blank image by Pillow/PIL.

[image]

```py
import base64
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

# Get size of image `sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_BIG_SMILE`
buffer = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_BIG_SMILE))
im1 = Image.open(buffer)
width, height = im1.size

# Create a blank image
im2 = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), "#ffffff00")
with BytesIO() as output:
    im2.save(output, format="PNG")
    blank = output.getvalue()

# Image state of button saved in `element.metadata`
layout = [[sg.Button("", image_data=blank, key=(j, i), metadata=False) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break
    elif type(event) == tuple:
        element = window[event]
        if element.metadata:
            element.update(image_data=blank)
        else:
            element.update(image_data=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_BIG_SMILE)
        element.metadata = not element.metadata

window.close()
```

Comment: I'm getting two error when running this, the "BytesIO" is not found (I fixed by importing it from "io", which I didn't know, but looked it up), and "base64" is also giving me some troubles.
But indeed that is a hell of a good idea, I need to try this code.

Comment: Ok I can't re-edit it, but I made it work. This IS exactly what a needed, this will help me a lot to go on, thank you so much!